# #Resolved - Positional parameter does not exist in query // stored function call

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, stored-functions, hibernate-entitymanager

I have this method to call a stored function from ORACLE, in java (spring) - using entity manager + createNativeQuery ..

```
(...)
String set_professional = "{? = call
    pk_backoffice.set_professional(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?}";
//32 parameters IN

query = entity.createNativeQuery(set_professional);
(...)
```

And everytime I try to test it, it shows:
    Positional parameter does not exist: 31 in query: {? = call (...)
But do I have something at position 31..it exists..

```
query.setParameter(31, prof.getFax()); // fax
```

Also, I started the parameters at 1 cause in previous exceptions it said it was 1-based
I've tried with a string and a null value instead of the get, still the same outcome..
About the query, I also counted the ? many times, so I'm sure it has 32 (for parameters) + 1(return - first ?)...

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you've resolved your question, you should yourself post an answer and then accept it when you can

Comment: oh, thank you, i'll do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, I replaced all ? for variables, even the first one, and the error disappeared.

Comment: be careful, your application is now vulnerable to Sql Injection.